# Replace in strings of list

Tags: python, string

I can use `re.sub` easily in single string like this:

```
  >>> a = "ajhga':&+?%"
  >>> a = re.sub('[.!,;+?&:%]', '', a)
  >>> a
      "ajhga'"
```

If I use this on list of strings then I am not getting the result. What I am doing is:

```
  >>> a = ["abcd:+;", "(l&'kka)"]
  >>> for x in a:
        ...     x = re.sub('[\(\)&\':+]', '', x)
        ... 
  >>> a
      ['abcd:+;', "(l&'kka)"]
```

How can I strip expressions from strings in list?

Comment: Depending on what your intended result strings are, you may consider the opposite approach where you indicate what you want to keep (whitelist) and strip out all other characters.  This is easily done with list comprehensions, rather than `re`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index,x in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = re.sub('[\(\)&\':+]', '', x)
```

Your changing the value but not updating your list. enumerate is function that return tuple `(index,value)`  for each item of list

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ["abcd:+;", "(l&'kka)"]
>>> a = [re.sub('[\(\)&\':+]', '', x) for x in a]
>>> a
['abcd;', 'lkka']
>>>
```