# Replace a group in strings of list using regex match

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Similar (not a duplicate) to this question:
[Replace in strings of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310396/replace-in-strings-of-list)

I would like to replace a particular group only out of the regex that matched. How could that be done?

Example:

Input:

```
list of strings, a = ['  /abc/def/zx -a 12 -b 12 -c 14 -d 15 --pqr -A $done1  ', 'abc','def']
```

Output: for the regex match, group 2 replaced with a string, say `time`

```
a = ['  /abc/def/zx -a 12 -b 12 -c 14 -d 15 --pqr -A $done1  ', 'abc','def']
for index,x in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = re.sub('(.*zx )(.*)( -A \$done1)', 'time', x)
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Like using a replace callback https://ideone.com/m9TWxe ?

Comment: `a[index] = re.sub('(.*zx )(.*)( -A \$done1)', r'\g<1>time\g<3>', x)`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/YyntT8)